# R: Is it possible to combine the boolean data in multiple select columns of partially duplicate rows?

Tags: r, dataframe, duplicates, boolean, aggregate

First off, I apologize for so horrendously wording my question. I cannot figure out a better, more succinct way of writing it, so hopefully what follows will help make it clear - any suggestions to improve its clarity are welcome, so as to make it more accessible to people in the future struggling with the same thing.

I am working with a dataframe in R which contains some rows with duplicate ID tags. There are four columns associated with each row which contain boolean values, and per row only one registers as true, in such a way that if an ID tag is repeated, the columns in which the boolean is true will be different. Below is a very short example section of the data I am working with:

```
dbsid     l_e      l_d      n_e      b_c
CCH00090  TRUE     FALSE    FALSE    FALSE
CCH00091  FALSE    FALSE    TRUE     FALSE
CCH00090  FALSE    TRUE     FALSE    FALSE
```

I am hoping to end up with the following (though on a much larger scale):

```
dbsid     l_e      l_d      n_e      b_c
CCH00090  TRUE     TRUE     FALSE    FALSE
CCH00091  FALSE    FALSE    TRUE     FALSE
```

but cannot figure out any way to go about producing such an output. Note that the boolean data in the case of the duplicate entry has been combined so that the true values are kept over the false ones. I've been looking at the aggregate function, but have had no luck coercing it into performing the above.

Is it possible to do so? Thanks for taking the time to read through my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with `summarize_all` from `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(dbsid) %>%
  summarize_all(sum)
```

**Result:**

```
# A tibble: 2 x 5
     dbsid   l_e   l_d   n_e   b_c
    <fctr> <int> <int> <int> <int>
1 CCH00090     1     1     0     0
2 CCH00091     0     0     1     0
```

or with `any` (@Ryan):

```
df %>%
  group_by(dbsid) %>%
  summarize_all(any)
```

**Result:**

```
# A tibble: 2 x 5
     dbsid   l_e   l_d   n_e   b_c
    <fctr> <lgl> <lgl> <lgl> <lgl>
1 CCH00090  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
2 CCH00091 FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
```

**Data:**

```
df = structure(list(dbsid = structure(c(1L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("CCH00090", 
"CCH00091"), class = "factor"), l_e = c(TRUE, FALSE, FALSE), 
    l_d = c(FALSE, FALSE, TRUE), n_e = c(FALSE, TRUE, FALSE), 
    b_c = c(FALSE, FALSE, FALSE)), .Names = c("dbsid", "l_e", 
"l_d", "n_e", "b_c"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```

Comment: Thanks useR - I've tried both solutions applied to my whole dataset, and they both work great!

Comment: @T.Zaborniak Glad that it helps. Unfortunately, you can only accept one answer. Feel free to pick the one that you find the most helpful.

Answer (score 3):

You can apply the `any` function across all the rows having the same `dbsid`, for all variables.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)

df[, lapply(.SD, any), by = dbsid]

#       dbsid   l_e   l_d   n_e   b_c
# 1: CCH00090  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
# 2: CCH00091 FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
```

Data used

```
df <- fread("dbsid     l_e      l_d      n_e      b_c
CCH00090  TRUE     FALSE    FALSE    FALSE
CCH00091  FALSE    FALSE    TRUE     FALSE
CCH00090  FALSE    TRUE     FALSE    FALSE")
```

Comment: Thanks Ryan! I just applied your solution to my whole dataset and it worked flawlessly.